# Lottie 2.8.0 with AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Tags: java, android, lottie

I wanted to install Lottie 2.8.0 in android 3.1.1 but in compiling the library I've got this error.
I've read the others question but didn't help me on this issue. What should I do to solve it?
The error message:**AAPT2 error: check logs for details**

Where can I find the logs? And how to solve it?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: add full error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into similar problem few days ago and after a bit of search i found this on bottom of their official github page:
https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android

> Lottie 2.8.0 and above only supports projects that have been migrated
>   to androidx. For more information, read Google's migration guide.

So you have two options either migrate your project to androidx or downgrade your library version to `2.7.0.` I am using following right now:

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
```